# Match date and assign name in multiple columns in R?

Tags: r

My apology for unclear question title!

My problem is i have a data set which has a column called real.date. Each ID will have several real.date dates. I would like to convert real.date into a name where it should be using 3 columns called date.1, date.2 and date.3. The rule is to allow ±5 days different.

```
id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
real.date = c('21-06-16','29-08-16','21-11-16','20-06-16','28-08-16','20-11-16','22-06-16','30-08-16','22-11-16')
date.1 = c('21-06-16','21-06-16','21-06-16','20-06-16','20-06-16','20-06-16','22-06-16','22-06-16','22-06-16')
date.2 = c('29-08-16','29-08-16','29-08-16','28-08-16','28-08-16','28-08-16','30-08-16','30-08-16','30-08-16')
date.3 = c('21-11-16','21-11-16','21-11-16','20-11-16','20-11-16','20-11-16','19-11-16','19-11-16','19-11-16')
df = cbind(id,real.date,date.1,date.2,date.3)

df
       id  real.date  date.1     date.2     date.3    
 [1,] "1" "21-06-16" "21-06-16" "29-08-16" "21-11-16"
 [2,] "1" "29-08-16" "21-06-16" "29-08-16" "21-11-16"
 [3,] "1" "21-11-16" "21-06-16" "29-08-16" "21-11-16"
 [4,] "2" "20-06-16" "20-06-16" "28-08-16" "20-11-16"
 [5,] "2" "28-08-16" "20-06-16" "28-08-16" "20-11-16"
 [6,] "2" "20-11-16" "20-06-16" "28-08-16" "20-11-16"
 [7,] "3" "22-06-16" "22-06-16" "30-08-16" "19-11-16"
 [8,] "3" "30-08-16" "22-06-16" "30-08-16" "19-11-16"
 [9,] "3" "22-11-16" "22-06-16" "30-08-16" "19-11-16"
```

I expect to have  a result like this

```
id  real.date
1   date.1
1   date.2
1   date.3
2   date.1
2   date.2
2   date.3
3   date.1
3   date.2
3   date.3
```

Any help is greatly appreciate!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by converting strings to dates using `as.Date`:

```
day.diff <- as.Date(df[, 3:5]) - as.Date(df[, 2])
day.diff <- matrix(as.numeric(day.diff), nrow = nrow(df))

x <- apply(day.diff, 1, function(x){
    res <- which(abs(x) <= 5)
    print(length(res))
    if(length(res) > 1){ # more than 1 col meets the requirement
        res <- res[1]
    }else if(length(res) == 0){ #' none of the cols meets the requirement
        res <- NA
    }
    res
})

new.df <- data.frame(id = df[, 1], real.date = colnames(df)[3:5][x])
#   id real.date
# 1  1    date.1
# 2  1    date.2
# 3  1    date.3
# 4  2    date.1
# 5  2    date.2
# 6  2    date.3
# 7  3    date.1
# 8  3    date.2
# 9  3      <NA>
```

---

note: the last row in your example didn't meet your rule of at most 5d difference.

---

if `df` is a data.frame, we can derive `day.diff` matrix by:

```
day.diff <- sapply(3:5, function(i) as.Date(df[, i]) - as.Date(df[, 2]))
# this is also applicable if df is a matrix
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I followed this and got the warnings:  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "-.Date") for "-"

Comment: I also tried as.POSIXct but it did not seem to work out

Comment: @PNY, could you show the line of code that is throwing the error? I guess you operation is between different data types. Make sure both side is date.

Comment: first i used day.diff <- as.Date(df[, 6:10]) - as.Date(df[, 5]) then it didn't work out. I checked str() for both and they showed up all Date format. Then I changed to df[, 6:10] - df[, 5] and got this error.

Comment: @PNY, seems that you are using a different `df`, which happened to be a `data.frame`. I have edited my answer to deal with `data.frame`. In your case, you can try `sapply(6:10, function(i) as.Date(df[, i]) - as.Date(df[, 5]))`. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: @mt1002 it works perfectly. I was trying to write an else if function for this before i read your comment but now i dont need that function anymore. Thank you very for your help. I really appreciate it :)